# .Net Core SignalR - connection timeout - heartbeat timer - connection state change handling

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

just to be clear up-front, this questions is about .Net Core SignalR, not the previous version.

The new SignalR has an issue with WebSockets behind IIS (I can't get them to work on Chrome/Win7/IIS express). So instead I'm using Server Sent Events (SSE).
However, the problem is that those time out after about 2 minutes, the connection state goes from 2 to 3. Automatic reconnect has been removed (apparently it wasn't working really well anyway in previous versions).

I'd like to implement a heartbeat timer now to stop clients from timing out, a tick every 30 seconds may well do the job.

**Update 10 November**

I have now managed to implement the server side Heartbeat, essentially taken from Ricardo Peres' https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/signalr-in-asp-net-core

- in startup.cs, add to `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)`

```cs
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>  
    {  
        routes.MapHub<TheHubClass>("signalr");  
    });

    TimerCallback SignalRHeartBeat = async (x) => {   
    await serviceProvider.GetService<IHubContext<TheHubClass>>().Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Heartbeat", DateTime.Now); };
    var timer = new Timer(SignalRHeartBeat).Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

- HubClass

For the HubClass, I have added `public async Task HeartBeat(DateTime now) => await Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Heartbeat", now);`

Obviously, both the timer, the data being sent (I'm just sending a DateTime) and the client method name can be different.

### Update .Net Core 2.1+

See the comment below; the timer callback should no longer be used. I've now implemented an IHostedService (or rather the abstract BackgroundService) to do that:

```
public class HeartBeat : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IHubContext<SignalRHub> _hubContext;
    public HeartBeat(IHubContext<SignalRHub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Heartbeat", DateTime.Now, stoppingToken);
            await Task.Delay(30000, stoppingToken);
        }            
    }
}
```

In your startup class, wire it in after `services.AddSignalR();`:

```
services.AddHostedService<HeartBeat>();
```

- Client

```js
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/signalr", { transport: signalR.TransportType.ServerSentEvents });
    connection.on("Heartbeat", serverTime => { console.log(serverTime); });
```

**Remaining pieces of the initial question**

What is left is how to properly reconnect the client, e.g. after IO was suspended (the browser's computer went to sleep, lost connection, changed Wifis or whatever)

I have implemented a client side Heartbeat that is working properly, at least until the connection breaks:

- Hub Class: `public async Task HeartBeatTock() => await Task.CompletedTask;`
- Client:

  var heartBeatTockTimer;
  function sendHeartBeatTock() {
     connection.invoke("HeartBeatTock");
  }
  connection.start().then(args => {
     heartBeatTockTimer = setInterval(sendHeartBeatTock, 10000);
  });

After the browser suspends IO for example, the invoke method would throw an exception - which cannot be caught by a simple try/catch because it is async.
What I tried to do for my HeartBeatTock was something like (pseudo-code):

```
function sendHeartBeatTock
    try connection.invoke("HeartbeatTock)
    catch exception
         try connection.stop()
         catch exception (and ignore it)
         finally
              connection = new HubConnection().start()
    repeat try connection.invoke("HeartbeatTock")
    catch exception
        log("restart did not work")
        clearInterval(heartBeatTockTimer)
        informUserToRefreshBrowser()
```

Now, this does not work for a few reasons. invoke throws the exception after the code block executes due to being run asynchronous. It looks as though it exposes a .catch() method, but I'm not sure how to implement my thoughts there properly.
The other reason is that starting a new connection would require me to re-implement all server calls like "connection.on("send"...) - which appears silly.

Any hints as to how to properly implement a reconnecting client would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, one mystery solved. If I inject IServiceProvider into the Configure method, I can probably set this up. Vital piece of information...

Comment: So this works:
`app.UseSignalR(routes => { routes.MapHub<SignalRHub>("signalr"); });
            TimerCallback SignalRHeartBeat = async (x) => { await serviceProvider.GetService<IHubContext<SignalRHub>>().Clients.All.InvokeAsync("Heartbeat", DateTime.Now); };
            var timer = new Timer(SignalRHeartBeat).Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));`
I shall update my question, now only the Client is left to take care of.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  Question about the server side code.  I'm getting ObjectDisposedException when the timer fires. My ServiceProvider is dead by the time the timer fires.  Did you have this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: @EricVaughan https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641557/221683

Comment: I had to register my app's message handlers in an independent store otherwise they're lost when a new connection is created. When a message arrives, the connection's 'on' handler iterates over the collection, forwarding the message.

Comment: Just FYI, there have been a few changes to all of this in the meantime; you may want to read https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3076 and https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4148 to see a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a working solution now (tested in Chrome and FF so far). In the hope to either motivate you to come up with something better, or to save you a little while coming up with something like this yourselves, I'm posting my solution here:

The Heartbeat-"Tick" message (the server routinely pinging the clients) is described in the question above.
The client ("Tock" part) now has:

- a function to register the connection, so that the callback methods (connection.on()) can be repeated; they'd be lost after just restarting a "new HubConnection" otherwise
- a function to register the TockTimer
- and a function to actually send Tock pings

The tock method catches errors upon sending, and tries to initiate a new connection. Since the timer keeps running, I'm registering a new connection and then simply sit back and wait for the next invocation.
Putting the client together:

```js
// keeps the connection object
var connection = null;
// stores the ID from SetInterval
var heartBeatTockTimer = 0;
// how often should I "tock" the server
var heartBeatTockTimerSeconds = 10;
// how often should I retry after connection loss?
var maxRetryAttempt = 5;
// the retry should wait less long then the TockTimer, or calls may overlap
var retryWaitSeconds = heartBeatTockTimerSeconds / 2;
// how many retry attempts did we have?
var currentRetryAttempt = 0;
// helper function to wait a few seconds
$.wait = function(miliseconds) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() { defer.resolve(); }, miliseconds);
    return defer;
};
// first routine start of the connection
registerSignalRConnection();
function registerSignalRConnection() {
    ++currentRetryAttempt;
    if (currentRetryAttempt > maxRetryAttempt) {
        console.log("Clearing registerHeartBeatTockTimer");
        clearInterval(heartBeatTockTimer);
        heartBeatTockTimer = 0;
        throw "Retry attempts exceeded.";
    }
    if (connection !== null) {
        console.log("registerSignalRConnection was not null", connection);
        connection.stop().catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    console.log("Creating new connection");
    connection = new signalR.HubConnection("/signalr", { transport: signalR.TransportType.ServerSentEvents });
    connection.on("Heartbeat", serverTime => { console.log(serverTime); });
    connection.start().then(() => {
        console.log("Connection started, starting timer.");
        registerHeartBeatTockTimer();
    }).catch(exception => {
        console.log("Error connecting", exception, connection);
    });
}
function registerHeartBeatTockTimer() {
    // make sure we're registered only once
    if (heartBeatTockTimer !== 0) return;
    console.log("Registering registerHeartBeatTockTimer");
    if (connection !== null)
        heartBeatTockTimer = setInterval(sendHeartBeatTock, heartBeatTockTimerSeconds * 1000);
    else
        console.log("Connection didn't allow registry");
}

function sendHeartBeatTock() {
    console.log("Standard attempt HeartBeatTock");
    connection.invoke("HeartBeatTock").then(() => { 
         console.log("HeartbeatTock worked.") })
         .catch(err => {
             console.log("HeartbeatTock Standard Error", err);
             $.wait(retryWaitSeconds * 1000).then(function() {
                 console.log("executing attempt #" + currentRetryAttempt.toString());
             registerSignalRConnection();
         });
         console.log("Current retry attempt: ", currentRetryAttempt);
     });
 }
```

Comment: Could you post the ServerSide, too ?

Comment: @EricBrunner Have a look at the question, it shows the server part

Comment: @ExternalUse Also need the `HeartbeatTock` method on the server.

Comment: Also, `currentRetryAttempt` should be reset when a new connection has successfully been created.

Comment: Do you need heartbeats both from server side and client side? If so, why?

Comment: @Cowborg See the answer below. On SSE transport (and potentially websockets) IIS closes idle connections at some point. I also use the tock message to send the server's timestamp and connection information in order to filter or act on particular messages. Up to you, you can try it without.

Comment: @ExternalUse: Thanks for you reply! So if I *only* use the Client-> Server heartbeat, will IIS close connection?  (or which of them (C->S or S->C) are neccessary. I did C->S (your Tock) only and it seems to work ok overnight, but I want to be sure I didnt misunderstand you)

Comment: @Cowborg This may well have changed since I wrote this; I'm using this method ever since with the newest SignalR and didn't have any problems. Whether the computer goes to sleep and wakes up again, or the connection is lost temporarily, it always comes back. IIS used to close the connection, not sure this still applies or even ever applied to Websockets. Some work you'll have to do for yourself ;-)

Comment: Haha, yes I totally get that, but as you imply different browsers behaves differently and extensivly testing different timeouts in browser, IIS, client takes time to I was mostly interested in the technical reason for S->C heartbeat (I dont know under what circumstances IIS closes connection and if a S->C heartbeat helps that). I hope you dont see this as Im questioning your solution, just trying to understand all solutions instead of just copy-paste code from internet blindly

Comment: @Cowborg I understand. I'm afraid I can't answer your particular question. As mentioned, I'm using those message to transfer connection IDs and timestamps to the client, and haven't had any problem since - therefore I left it in peace. Haven't tried what happens without it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/issues/835) when running SignalR Core behind IIS. IIS will close idle connections after 2 minutes. The long term plan is to add keep alive messages which, as a side effect, will prevent IIS from closing the connection. To work around the problem for now you can:

- send periodically a message to the clients
- change the idle-timeout setting in IIS as [described](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(v=ws.10).aspx) here
- restart the connection on the client side if it gets closed
- use a different transport (e.g. long polling since you cannot use webSockets on Win7/Win2008 R2 behind IIS)

Comment: Thanks Pawel! The server timeout problem is solved, I've implemented the timer (see my comment above). The only remaining thing is a client re-connect after e.g. IO suspended or any other change of state of the connection. I can't figure out how to access that in the client library.

Comment: I have updated my question to show the implemented server-side, and my (failed) attempt to reconnect the client.

Answer (score 1):

Client version based on ExternalUse's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249132/221683)...

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr'
import _ from 'lodash'

var connection = null;
var sendHandlers = [];
var addListener = f => sendHandlers.push(f);

function registerSignalRConnection() {

    if (connection !== null) {
        connection.stop().catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl('myHub')
        .build();

    connection.on("Heartbeat", serverTime =>
        console.log("Server heartbeat: " + serverTime));

    connection.on("Send", data =>
        _.each(sendHandlers, value => value(data)));

    connection.start()
        .catch(exception =>
            console.log("Error connecting", exception, connection));
}

registerSignalRConnection();

setInterval(() =>
    connection.invoke("HeartBeatTock")
        .then(() => console.log("Client heatbeat."))
        .catch(err => {    
            registerSignalRConnection();
        }), 10 * 1000);

export { addListener };
```