# .Net Core 2.1 - Cannot access a disposed object.Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I just migrated .NET Core 2.0 to .NET Core 2.1. Everything went fine, but when I try to login now I get the folowing error:

> - $exception  {System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>     Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.

This happens in this bit of code:

```
public class AppContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

    public AppContractResolver(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var httpContextAccessor = _services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;

        List<JsonProperty> properies = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization).ToList();

        properies = FilterOneClaimGranted(type, properies, user);

        return properies;
    }
```

It happens on this line:

```
var httpContextAccessor = _services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
```

This did work on .NET Core 2.0

I have tried adding the `HttpContextAccessor` to my startup, but that did not work.

So, how do I fix this?

Let me know if you need more code. I will happily provide more, but I don't know what you might or might not need, so therefor I did not add a lot of code.'

**EDIT**

I have added `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` to my startup, but that does not seem to work. Still getting the error.

**EDIT 2:**

Full stacktrace:

```
- $exception    {System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at WebAPI.Extensions.AppContractResolver.CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization) in C:\Users\luukw\Desktop\stage\blacky-api\Blacky\Extensions\Resolver\AppContractResolver.cs:line 25
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)}    System.ObjectDisposedException
```

Comment: just wanting to check, are you registering it in the .net core 2.1 way of calling `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

Comment: I have tried adding it, but did not work. Still got the same error

Comment: Instead calling AddHttpContextAccessor try register it manually, helped in my case: services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>()

Comment: @Vitaly Nope, does not work :(

Comment: Did you try injecting HttpContextAccessor to you constructor? Also HttpContextAccessor has to be registered manually.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I can't check right now, but just to test, can you try using IActionContextAccessor instead? Register like this: services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>(), then change your code to _services.GetRequiredService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext.HttpContext.User

Comment: I have the same issue. It doesn't seem to be related to IHttpContextAccessor, but to somethihng else.

Comment: AppContractResolver(IServiceProvider services,   IHttpContextAccessor httpcontextaccessor)
    {
        _services = services;
this.httpContextAccessor =httpcontextaccessor;
    }

And in RegisterServices in Startup.cs add,
 services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

Comment: @CodeNameJack Hmmmmmm.... While this does work, I don't know if this is the right way of doing things...

Comment: Don't put your workaround in the question, post it as your own answer. And your "workaround" actually is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Hmmmmm.... Okay, did not know this is the correcty way. I will first wait for CodeNameJack to post an answer because he came up with the answer. If he doesn't answer within like a day, I will post an answer.

Comment: @CodeNameJack See comment above

Comment: You should try to avoid passing in a `IServiceProvider` to your classes and instead pass in the actual thing you need to use. It solves some edge cases (like yours) and it makes it easier to see what your class is actually using for it's dependencies.

Comment: @LuukWuijster also a helpful tip, any time you need to "delay" the resolve or resolve it multiple times you can pass in a `Func<YourTypeHere> yourTypeFactory` to your function and calling a `var foo = yourTypeFactory()` is exactly the same as doing `var foo = serviceprovider.Resolve<YourTypeHere>()`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Oh okay, I didn't know that. That can be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of calling
 `services.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()`, inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to the constructor and use aprivate field to store the value.

```
public AppContractResolver(IServiceProvider services, 
                           IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
   _services = services;
   this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
}
```

Also HttpContextAccessor has to be registered manually.
In RegisterServices in `Startup.cs` add, `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Comment: `IServiceProvider` is registered by the framework. It's the container itself

Comment: @MatanShahar just a FYI the answer was updated and now contains correct info.

Comment: using IHttpContextAccessor is not recommended

Comment: The fact has nothing to do with the answer, The OP wanted to access `IHttpContextAccessor` in a service, and the answer provides a way to do that correctly.

Answer (score 18):

In my case issue was in `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
{
   var svc = services.GetService<IService>(); // <-- exception here
}
```

just replace `services.GetService<>()` with `app.ApplicationServices.GetService<>()`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   var svc = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IService>(); // no exception
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I have a ServiceLocator and I could make this Change:
`private static IServiceProvider _provider;

        public static void Init(IServiceProvider provider)
        {
            _provider = provider;
        }

public static T Resolve<T>() => (T)_provider.GetService(typeof(T));

"To:"
private static IApplicationBuilder _app;

        public static void Init(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            _app = app;
        }

        public static T Resolve<T>() => (T)_app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(T));`

Comment: OMG: the `app.ApplicationServices` is the most amazing find! Thank you for the suggestion that saved me even more hours of continued research, trial and error.

Comment: :'( I've spent worth time, but I've improved my patience : D thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you create any transient service, such as services.AddTransient... then .net core will dispose the service provider. This is a bug as of .net core 2.2.

Comment: Any Github link to this issue?

Comment: Bug seems to be gone in .net core 3

Answer (score 2):

For me it works with:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  …
  services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
  …
}
```

and then:

```
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
    ...
    ...accessor.HttpContext.RequestService

     ...

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error and it took a long time to resolve, so I am going to post it here.

Here is the code that was throwing the error:

```
using var context = this.DbFactory.CreateDbContext();                
SqlParameter[] parameter =
{
    new SqlParameter("@ord_cust_id", ordCustId)
};
products = await context.GetProduct.FromSqlRaw<ProductEntity>($"{spName}  @ord_cust_id", parameter).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

The exception that was thrown was on the last line.  It made no sense as the context was being created by the DbFactory, and so there is no way that it could be disposed already.

After a lot of searching, the scope of the DbFactory was found to be "Transient" so that was changed to Singleton, and the exception was resolved.

This is the code in startup:

```
 services.AddDbContextFactory<CDSEntities>(options =>
 {                
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
 }, ServiceLifetime.Singleton); //changed to Singlton instead of Transient
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I didn't have the async await on the rest API method, so it was disposing the IServiceProvider before the end of the call.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar exception when trying to get service inside the `Startup ➢ ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<INotification>(provider =>
    {
        var hubContext = (IHubContext<NotificationHub>)provider
                  .GetService(typeof(IHubContext<NotificationHub>));

        // ↓↓↓ Exception: cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
        var mediator = (IMediator)provider.GetService(typeof(IMediator)); 

        hubContext.SetListener(() =>  
            mediator.Send(new ...);
            ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

FYI: `NotificationHub` is my custom notification class implementing the custom `INotificaiton` service.

---

Solved the problem by creating a local scoped service:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<INotification>(provider =>
    {
        var hubContext = (IHubContext<NotificationHub>)provider
                  .GetService(typeof(IHubContext<NotificationHub>));

          var myScope = provider.CreateScope(); // <<< creating a scoped sertvice
          var mediator = (IMediator)myScope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMediator));

          hubContext.SetListener(() =>  
             mediator.Send(new ...);
             ...
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "await" operator was missing in the caller method.

```
    public async Task<OrderResponse> CreateOrder(){
    //Do something
    var response = **await** CreateOrderItem();
    return response;
}

public async Task<ItemResponse> CreateOrderItem(){
    //Do something
}
```

"await" was missing in CreateOrder()

Comment: This was useful for me, I had the same thing happen in a controller method.