# .Net Core 2.1: ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-2.1

While migrating my existing .Net Core 1.1 project to .Net Core 2.1. I have added DbContext to the service on ConfigureService method as shown below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{  
   //Configure the DB Context
   services.AddDbContext<AxDataContext>(options => 
   axDbContextOption.Configure(options), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
}
```

Later, I tried to get the service like this.

```
private AxDataContext DataContext = 
this.ServiceProvider.GetService<AxDataContext>();
```

which encountered an error like this.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()

Stack Query Cookies Headers
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
 Object name: 'IServiceProvider'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException()
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService<T>(IServiceProvider provider)
Aximpro.Framework.WebCore.Providers.PageProvider.get_DataContext() in PageProvider.cs
+
        private AxDataContext DataContext => this.mDataContext ?? (this.mDataContext = this.ServiceProvider.GetService<AxDataContext>());
```

[Stack Trace Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beGz8.jpg)

The same piece of code is working perfectly in .Net Core 1.1. Though [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619696/net-core-2-1-cannot-access-a-disposed-object-object-name-iserviceprovider) describes the similar issue, still I didn't understand, Is there anything changed in .Net Core 2.1 while getting registered services back.

Comment: So what's happening to this.ServiceProvider in the mean time?

Comment: this.ServiceProvider has this,
{Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope}
    
Engine: {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine}
    
ServiceProvider: {Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope}

Comment: This was a breaking change made in 2.1 https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/1446.

Comment: @davidfowl Is my understanding correct that this breaking change will be reverted in .NET Core 2.2?

Comment: Not quite. We haven’t done that work.